# Implementation of MonadState without using return?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

For a practical assignment I have to implement `MonadSate` in Haskell, without using the `return` function, and by defining `get` and `put` in terms of `modify`, and `modify` in terms of `get` and `put`.

```hs
     class Monad m ⇒ MonadState m s | m → s where
     get :: m s
     put :: s → m ()
     modify :: (s → s) → m s
```

I got these laws that I can use:

```hs
put s1 >> put s2 ≡ put s2
put s >> get ≡ put s >> return s
get >>= put ≡ return ()
get >>= (λs → get >>= k s) ≡ get >>= (λs → k s s)
```

I tried the following:

```hs
     class (Monad m) => MonadState m s | m -> s where
       get :: m s
       get = modify (\s -> s)

       put :: s -> m ()
       put s = modify (\_ -> s) >> return ()

       modify :: (s -> s) -> m s
       modify f = do
         s <- get
         put (f s) >> get
```

But I am using `return ()`, which is not allowed

I do not understand how when replacing the old state with the new one, I can return an empty tuple, when the result-type of modify is `m s`, and not `m ()`

Comment: You could use `fmap` or `<$` but I'm not sure if you're allowed to use those. Is the exercise precise about which functions you are allowed to use?

Comment: it does not say anything about what i am allowed to use, only what is required minimally:
no use of return, get and put defined in terms of modify, and modify defined in terms of get and put, and of course those laws.

Comment: @misterMonkeyMan, your final sentence correctly shows that that's impossible without the use of some other function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `fmap (const ())` would be a fair game, because it can't be said to be just `return` in a trench coat.

Answer (score 2):

Piggy-backing on the comment from Fyodor: to distill your problem, you have a value of type `m s` and you want a value of type `m ()`. So what you're looking for is some function `f :: m s -> m ()`. There are a number of ways to implement this function.

One way, which you already discovered, is to use `return ()`:

```
f :: (Monad m) => m a -> m ()
f = (>> return ())
```

Another way, is simply to use the properties of `Monad`, which is a subclass of `Functor`. As a reminder, `fmap` has the signature `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. So, you'd need some function `g :: a -> ()` such that

```
f :: (Monad m) => m a -> m ()
f = fmap g
```

There is only one such implementation of `g`.

---

As an added exercise, it's useful to think about what the semantics are when using `(>>)` versus `fmap` in this exercise.

Comment: duuuuude, thanks, this explanation made me understand it. deadline passed but when i implemented it, it worked!! thank you very much!